# Are there any methods for fitting "interconnected" AR with cross-lags at times older than 0?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, vector-autoregression, arma

I'm not really sure how to explain this, so any advice about the terminology would be very welcome!

So let's say that I have two independently driven AR(2) models that are connected together, for example:

$x_1(t)=a_{11} x_1(t-1)+a_{12} x_1(t-2) +a_{13} x_2(t-1) + a_{14} x_2(t-2)+\eta_1(t)$
$x_2(t)=a_{21} x_2(t-1)+a_{22} x_2(t-2) +a_{23} x_1(t-1) + a_{24} x_1(t-2)+\eta_2(t)$

I need to generate coefficients that will in the end produce a "signal" that will fit into a certain frequency band.

I understand that this is probably a huge topic, so I'm mostly looking for general diections in which to research further.

Comment: Keywords: vector autoregression (VAR; tag [tag:var]), vector autoregressive moving average (VARMA) model

Comment: @Richard Hardy Looks useful!

Comment: @Richard Hardy Sorry, things happened and I didn't have the time to go through it properly.

Comment: @Richard Hardy Thanks for reminding me! Yeah, the name helped a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have here is a **vector autoregression (VAR)** with lag order $p=2$ and dimension $K=2$. You can think of it as a natural extension to the scalar autoregressive (AR) model.

- In an AR($p$) you have a **scalar**-valued time series where the current value is a linear combination of $p$ past values (skipping the intercept for simplicity),

$$x_t=\varphi_1 x_{t-1}+\dotsc+\varphi_p x_{t-p}+\varepsilon_t.$$

- In a VAR($p$) you have a **vector**-valued time series with the current value of each of $K$ (scalar) components being a linear combination of $p$ past values of itself and other (scalar) components. In vector and matrix terms,

$$\mathbf{x}_t=\Phi_1 x_{t-1}+\dotsc+\Phi_p \mathbf{x}_{t-p}+\mathbf{\varepsilon}_t;$$

in scalar terms,

$$x_{i,t}=\varphi_{1,i1} x_{1,t-1} + \dotsc + \varphi_{1,iK} x_{K,t-1} + \dotsc + \varphi_{p,i1} x_{1,t-p} + \dotsc + \varphi_{p,iK} x_{K,t-p} + \varepsilon_{i,t}.$$